# Tinymce: How to save text with html tags ony?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

How do I configure tinymce to only save html tags and text.

My source file is `microsoft word` and if i cut and paste something from there is adds all kinds of metadata about the font family, formatting and so on which I don't need.

```
style=\"text-align:\r\n\"font-family...etc.etc.
```

I tried

```
entity_encoding:"raw"
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. I'm just looking for something like:

```
<p>Test</p>
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks very much

Comment: have you tried `strip_tags()` in case if you are using php to store it in db?

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of the **premium** TinyMCE.

From their feature page, under Premium: https://www.tinymce.com/features/

> **Improved Copy-Paste:**
>     Unrivaled technology that cleans your pasted Word content and matches
>     styles to your preference (works with images, too.)

As an alternative you could try CKEditor, http://ckeditor.com/ which has this functionality available as a configurable plugin:  http://ckeditor.com/addon/pastefromword

By the way, if you're doing this as a one off, I usually just paste text into a plain text editor like Notepad, which will strip all formatting and then copy and paste that again into your browser.

Comment: Great thanks very much for this! I will take a look at CKEditor